# SlowCheetah 2.5.48 not transforming web config on build

Tags: slowcheetah

So I have downloaded the latest SlowCheetah Visual Studio Extension v2.5.48.45331 and installed the latest NuGet Package. I have a custom build configuration named XL.Production and have the according Web.XL.Production.config file. When I publish, Web.XL.Production.config is picked up and everything's sugar, but when I hit F5, no go, Web.config settings are used even though XL.Production configuration is currently selected.

I have checked out this question: [SlowCheetah not transforming file on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500789/slowcheetah-not-transforming-file-on-build)

But the latest SlowCheetah is not using PropertyGroup any longer and instead relies on the NuGet Package.

So it's not working for me, it was clean install, we never had any previous version of SlowCheetah installed. We are using VS2013 w/Update 5.

p.s. Just a thought, why is such a critical functionality not built in into VS by default? Why should I have to install a NuGet package and a Visual Studio Extension to get this to work?

Comment: I don't know if this is compatible with VS2013, but you could try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18542140/slowcheetah-not-transforming-web-config-on-build/21039532#21039532

Comment: I have the same problem. with Visual studio 2015. Spent a day and not able to figure out. tried updating the project file and target file.  Any help?